# Broadcast Receiver with action PHONE_STATE is not working after App gets killed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, phone-state-listener

I want to get broadcast for incoming calls in my android device. and for this I have used the broadcast receiver with action PHONE_STATE & register it statically in AndroidManifest.xml as per below added screenshot :

[image]

This broadcast is working fine till my app is in foreground or active in recent apps. But It's not working after my app gets killed from recent apps.

and this broadcast action has exempted from limitation of broadcast mentioned in this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html

I have tried by registering this broadcast from my Activity & also by registering it statically in AndroidManifest.xml file But still I am not able to get any broadcast after my app killed from recent apps.

I want to get broadcast every time for all the incoming calls even after my is not active or got killed from receiver.

Please give some solution to achieve this. or
Please suggest me any other solution or any other broadcast through which I can achieve this.